# How to reload a jupyter notebook after a kernel restart?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In a jupyter notebook I would like to define a function in python, which, when called, does the following:

- Gives out an alert to the user
- Restarts the notebook kernel
- Marks the executed cell as done (i.e. without a star, `[ ]`)
- Focus is on the next cell

Or as an alternative:

- Gives out an alert to the user
- Restarts the notebook kernel
- Clears all the output of the entire notebook
- Focus is on the first cell again (like a F5 reload of the browser tab).

I have tried the following code

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def reload():
    display(HTML(
        '''
            <script>
                alert('This notebook needs to be restarted!');

                IPython.notebook.kernel.restart(); 
                IPython.display.clear_output();

                window.location.reload();

            </script>            
        '''
    ))
reload()
```

but it gives an error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'clear_output'
```

despite [this documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.clear_output).

When I remove the line

```
IPython.display.clear_output();
```

then the kernel is restarted, but I get 2(!) alerts and it looks like that the execution of the next cell is performed. Also, the cells are not cleared , the current cell still does have the star in the brackets (`[*]`).

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does what you described as the alternative option, with the addition of saving a checkpoint before reloading so the output stays cleared:

```py
from IPython.display import Javascript, display


def reload():
    display(
        Javascript('''
            // clear all output (based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47315713/9504155)           
            // save a reference to the cell we're currently executing inside of,
            // to avoid clearing it later (which would remove this js)
            var this_cell = $(element).closest('.cell').data('cell');
            function clear_other_cells () {
                Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().forEach(function (cell) {
                    if (cell.cell_type === 'code' && cell !== this_cell) {
                        cell.clear_output();
                    }
                    Jupyter.notebook.set_dirty(true);
                });
            }

            if (Jupyter.notebook._fully_loaded) {
                // notebook has already been fully loaded, so clear now
                clear_other_cells();
            }

            // save checkpoint so output stays cleared after reload
            IPython.notebook.save_checkpoint();

            IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();

            alert('This notebook needs to be restarted!');
            window.location.reload(false);
        '''))

reload()
```

If you prefer the first option (without reloading the page, focusing on the next cell instead) just remove the lines for saving a checkpoint and reloading and use the `IPython.display.clear_output()` function after the JavaScript part to clear the current cell's output as well:

```py
from IPython.display import Javascript, clear_output, display


def reload():
    display(
        Javascript('''
            // clear all output (based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47315713/9504155)           
            // save a reference to the cell we're currently executing inside of,
            // to avoid clearing it later (which would remove this js)
            var this_cell = $(element).closest('.cell').data('cell');
            function clear_other_cells () {
                Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().forEach(function (cell) {
                    if (cell.cell_type === 'code' && cell !== this_cell) {
                        cell.clear_output();
                    }
                    Jupyter.notebook.set_dirty(true);
                });
            }

            if (Jupyter.notebook._fully_loaded) {
                // notebook has already been fully loaded, so clear now
                clear_other_cells();
            }

            IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();

            alert('Notebook output cleared!');
        '''))
    clear_output()
```

`IPython.display.clear_output();` was not working in your code because it was called in the HTML `<script>` tag as JavaScript code instead of in Python.

Comment: It does not seem to clear the notebook. I still have output from other cells I ran before I called `reload()`.

Comment: That is strange because it works fine for me. Does it do anything if you remove the last few lines (everything after `// save checkpoint so output stays cleared after reload`)?

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. It seems to restart the kernel, cleans all the output, and I am in the next cell. Maybe that can be integrated to a solution...

Comment: Maybe I don't need to go back to the first cell (the first cell is supposed to check the environment, install packages if required and restart the kernel, so these new packages are being used).

Comment: In that case it might be best to skip the reloading part. Then you only need to clear the output of the current cell by calling `IPython.display.clear_output()` in Python after the JavaScript part. Would that work for you?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you what I mean (in the second code block).

Comment: It looks like your second solution is what I really can utilize for a practical use. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure to the other issues that you have encountered but the code

```
IPython.display.clear_output();
```

ran successfully without problems in my jupyter notebook, are you sure your jupyter notebook version is up to date or is the same version to that in the [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.clear_output)? It is not surprising that different versions may have different function name or even the whole structure may varies.

Comment: Maybe that command works and clears the code - but this standalone code does not help with my actual question. Also, it does not work (`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` or `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'clear_output'`).