# HTML request within a function

Tags: python, html, request, jupyter

I would like to have a function which can restart the kernel in jupyter notebook. The HTML statement below work well if I use it alone, but within a function it does not:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

def restart_kernel():
    HTML('<script>IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells()</script>')
```

It work only if I use it in a cell without any other code:

```
HTML('<script>IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells()</script>')
```

Why is that? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Roland

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58711404/how-to-reload-a-jupyter-notebook-after-a-kernel-restart) will help.  If not I can add an answer based on this that might help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add return for the function.

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

def restart_kernel():
     return HTML('<script>IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells()</script>')
```

I think it is about the local and global scope problem.
The outer side won't run HTML(...) because it did not get any return value.

Comment: The strange thing is that it works when the cell starts with the function, but if it is in for example an if statement it dost not work:
`if 1 == 1:

    restart_kernel()`

Why is that?